# How to drop P-Frames for Datamosh effect using FFMpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing

I'm trying to achieve the Datamosh effect on video.
[image: a Example of datamoshed Picture]
<sub>(source: [ilovenewwork.com](http://ilovenewwork.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/datamosh.jpg))</sub>

I know that in general what I need to the video is to delete all i-Frames but I have no idea how to achieve that using ffmpeg.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/604858/ffmpeg-extract-intra-frames-i-p-b-frames

Comment: Thanks, good info but still, if I drop the all the i-frames I simply get an image sequence that changes every 1 second. I assume I need to keep the first i-frame and extract all others. Have any idea how?

Comment: This will be tedious to do with FFmpeg, if at all. Try the Avidemux [method](https://www.reddit.com/r/brokenanimegifs/wiki/tutorial) instead.

Answer (score 3):

if you are just looking for an easy command line solution!

install the following ruby script https://github.com/ucnv/aviglitch

[nodejs version https://github.com/fand/node-aviglitch]

1. convert your video to AVI

**ffmpeg -i input.mp4 output1.avi**

2. datamosh it with the ruby script "aviglitch"

**datamosh output1.avi -o datamoshedvideo.avi**

3. (optional) convert your video back to mp4 (or whatever)

**ffmpeg -i datamoshedvideo.avi moshedbutoriginalext.mp4**