# H264 delete specific keyframes

Tags: java, ffmpeg, encode, h.264

I am trying to make some corrupted videos for a so called method "Datamosh". It is about to remove h264 keyframes so ones videos predictions is played on anothers video.
I am using ffmpeg.

My video looks like this:
I P P P P P P P P P P P P I P P P P P P P

How do i remove the second keyframe without encoding it and make a corrupted video?
If it is possible I want to use java.

Best regards!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to drop P-Frames for Datamosh effect using FFMpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37369450/how-to-drop-p-frames-for-datamosh-effect-using-ffmpeg)